# How to find the locator for, a class with 'flexItem' class name in Cypress

Tags: javascript, selenium, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

`<div class="FlexItem">Jun 18th, 2021&nbsp;(one-time payment)</div>`

I have only this above structure.

Comment: If you are trying to add an image it is not attached.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I have modified it now. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about cypress, but in Selenium where we use XPATH V1.0 it would be `//div[@class='FlexItem']`

Comment: How about using `div.FlexItem ` ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, cypress accepts CSS selectors which in the case would be `div.FlexItem`

```
cy.get('div.FlexItem').click()
```

If you want to use Xpath you have to install an external plugin [cypress-xpath](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath).

To install the plugin run the command -

```
npm install -D cypress-xpath
```

Go to `cypress/support/index.js` and write -

```
require('cypress-xpath')
```

After installation you can use:

```
cy.xpath('//div[@class='FlexItem']').click()
```

Comment: it's been just 3 minutes, let OP try first. Be patience , even if he wants he cannot accept before 7 mins